# Сравнительные степени наречия при опущенных глаголах

Tags: сравнительная-степень

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в следующих предложениях употреблены наречия сравнительной степени или прилагательные сравнительной степени?

Больше науки - умнее руки.
Днем позже, днем раньше - какая разница?

Ставлю от "Науки" вопрос "Сколько?" - больше. Не могу поставить вопрос "Какой?", поэтому отношу к наречиям. Глагол, выходит, опущен? В "Днем позже, днем раньше" также глагол опущен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Глагол, выходит, опущен?

Видимо, речь не о глаголе, а о сказуемом?

Больше науки - умнее руки. Больше науки - безлично-количественное генитивное предложение. Если перестроить предложение, восстановить его состав, получится: *Будет больше науки - будут умнее руки.*  Сравнительная степень наречия входит в состав сказуемого. (Правда, в науке так не говорят, говорится просто о главном члене предложения, не называя его). Руки будут какими? - будут умнее, умнее - сравнительная степень прилагательного.

(Это будет (было) когда?) Днем позже, днем раньше - какая разница? Позже, раньше - сравнит. степень наречия. Приимённые наречия в сравнительной степени входят в состав обстоятельства времени, сказуемое пропущено.